# Python versions and libraries

Tags: python, libraries, versions

For an internship I have applied for I have completed a task which was to create  a 2048 clone. My [solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQMGgYpvBpAZnMxR1BhdmdpRm8/view?usp=sharing) is found here. The brief said the following:

> Use either Python 2.7 or 3+ and if any 3rd party libraries are used add them in a requirements file parsable by pip. The game should be started by invoking the main file: python main.py

I just wanted to ask and make sure that everything will work when I send it to them. I have used the following imports:

```
from msvcrt import getch
import random
from copy import deepcopy
```

Do I need to add anything to the folder for these to work? And I need to make sure that it will print properly for them, as I tried on a different PC and the print statements acted differently and I am unsure as to why.

Comment: `msvcrt` requires Windows (or analog). Do you need it to work on OS X, Linux?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to make any kind of requirements file at all, as the `mscvrt`, `random`, and `copy` modules are part of python's standard library. However, the `mscvrt` module is only available on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add things to `requirements.txt` that are not part of the standard library.

`msvcrt`, `random` and `copy` are all part of the Python standard library and don't need to be added.